# Image upload ruined my links

Tags: permalinks, images

I uploaded an image that had the same file name as a page in my site. So "referrers.png" made my /referrer/ link become /referrer.png/ which obviously broke everything.

[image]

Comment: And your question is: please tell me what to do? Since you're on localhost you have full access to files and database to remove the offending files and entries.

Comment: Well obviously this is not correct. Nobody wants a broken site because of an image upload. i already deleted the image and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to rename and reupload the image and it cleared up.

This is clearly a bug as a image should not rewrite URLS like this.